# Different identifiers for prediction with glmer

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have created a model using glmer(). The battle_seq_num is the number of sessions, each player_idhas 100 sessions (observations). My goal is to make a prediction for the test sample whether they are going to buy a membership or not. xp is a continuous quantitative variable.

```
m2 <- glmer(is_tier_ten ~ xp + battle_seq_num + (battle_seq_num || player_id), family = binomial(link="logit"), control = glmerControl(optimize = "nloptwrap"), data = dfs)
```

summary(m2) returns:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: is_tier_ten ~ xp + battle_seq_num + (battle_seq_num || player_id)
   Data: dfs
Control: glmerControl(optimize = "nloptwrap")

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
 10911.5  10969.4  -5450.7  10901.5   799995 

Scaled residuals: 
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.01098  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.10277 

Random effects:
 Groups      Name           Variance  Std.Dev. 
 player_id   (Intercept)    1.476e-05  0.003841
 player_id.1 battle_seq_num 1.379e+03 37.130895
Number of obs: 800000, groups:  player_id, 8000

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)    -3.01428    0.34902  -8.636   <2e-16 ***
xp              0.07115    0.06879   1.034    0.301    
battle_seq_num -6.79224    0.40190 -16.900   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) xp    
xp          -0.047       
battl_sq_nm -0.921  0.025
```

Prediction:

```
str(p2 <- predict(m2,bs2, allow.new.levels = TRUE, type = "response"))
```

Result:

```
       39046        32744        36225        40022        37105        32809        39818        41095        38585        36820        40429 
1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 1.000000e+00 3.631456e-12 9.999998e-01 1.513329e-11 2.048973e-13 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 1.000000e+00 
       36854        42161         3625        40777        50639        37231        36263        36170        36179       159788       186746 
2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16 2.220446e-16
```

While my identifiers for bs2 are:

```
       [1]    7   10   16   27   29   32   37   51   58   60   64   75   77   80   87   90   98  102  103  108  113  121  122  130  136  141  150  166
  [29]  174  184  189  193  194  198  204  212  214  230  232  233  235  241  258  267  271  279  280  282  287  293  294  295  296  299  303  313
  [57]  315  330  336  346  347  355  358  361  367  387  399  404  405  414  420  424  432  446  454  456  459  469  472  484  488  495  496  506
  [85]  524  526  528  530  531  537  541  542  550  551  552  553  561  582  587  588  591  595  605  606  622  624  634  656  664  665  671  674
 [113]  676  680  681  691  694  702  705  711  714  717  720  722  729  734  737  744  759  760  765  766  772  777  786  789  793  804  819  823
 [141]  825  827  840  849  855  868  869  870  871  874  878  890  898  907  909  916  919  921  924  927  933  938  939  942  944  947  956  958
 [169]  961  974  980  984  987  989  990  991  997 1006 1007 1019 1022 1025 1028 1029 1031 1032 1034 1038 1043 1053 1055 1059 1060 1066 1071 1073
 [197] 1076 1077 1080 1092 1098 1100 1101 1104 1110 1114 1120 1126 1129 1133 1136 1137 1145 1150 1161 1163 1167 1169 1180 1185 1189 1193 1201 1203
```

Is there any way of making a prediction with the initials ids? Just a prediction of whether a person will become is_tier_ten generally for each id and not for every repeated obs (battle_seq_num). As a result, I have to make a .csv document for every id from bs2 with individual prediction.